# Сгруппировать массив в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как можно из такого массива:

```
[ELEMENTS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 38
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                        [PROP_PRICE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 9
                                [NAME] => Цена
                                [VALUE] => 100
                            )

                        [PROP_PERFORMANCE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 10
                                [NAME] => Производительность
                                [VALUE] => 300
                            )

                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 38
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                        [PROP_PRICE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 9
                                [NAME] => Цена
                                [VALUE] => 200
                            )

                        [PROP_PERFORMANCE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 10
                                [NAME] => Производительность
                                [VALUE] => 300
                            )

                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 38
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                        [PROP_PRICE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 9
                                [NAME] => Цена
                                [VALUE] => 200
                            )

                        [PROP_PERFORMANCE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 10
                                [NAME] => Производительность
                                [VALUE] => 500
                            )

                    )
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 38
                [PROPERTIES] => Array
                    (
                        [PROP_PRICE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 9
                                [NAME] => Цена
                                [VALUE] => 300
                            )

                        [PROP_PERFORMANCE] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 10
                                [NAME] => Производительность
                                [VALUE] => 600
                            )

                    )
            )
    )
```

получить примерно массив примерно такой структуры:

```
Производительность
 -300
 -500
 -600
Цена
 -100
 -200
 -300
```

Comment: про циклы слышали что-нибудь? попробуйте, отлично  справится в данном случае

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов решения множество, вот например.

```
$data['ELEMENTS'] = [
    [
        'ID' => 38,
        'PROPERTIES' => [
            'PROP_PRICE' => [
                'ID' => 9,
                'NAME' => 'Price',
                'VALUE' => 100
            ]
        ],
        'PROP_PERFORMANCE' => [
            'ID' => 10,
            'NAME' => 'Performance',
            'VALUE' => 300
        ]
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 39,
        'PROPERTIES' => [
            'PROP_PRICE' => [
                'ID' => 9,
                'NAME' => 'Price',
                'VALUE' => 200
            ]
        ],
        'PROP_PERFORMANCE' => [
            'ID' => 10,
            'NAME' => 'Performance',
            'VALUE' => 300
        ]
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 40,
        'PROPERTIES' => [
            'PROP_PRICE' => [
                'ID' => 9,
                'NAME' => 'Price',
                'VALUE' => 200
            ]
        ],
        'PROP_PERFORMANCE' => [
            'ID' => 10,
            'NAME' => 'Performance',
            'VALUE' => 500
        ]
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 41,
        'PROPERTIES' => [
            'PROP_PRICE' => [
                'ID' => 9,
                'NAME' => 'Price',
                'VALUE' => 300
            ]
        ],
        'PROP_PERFORMANCE' => [
            'ID' => 10,
            'NAME' => 'Performance',
            'VALUE' => 600
        ]
    ]
];

$newData = [];
foreach ($data['ELEMENTS'] as $key => $element) {
    {
        $newData['PROP_PRICE'][] = $element['PROPERTIES']['PROP_PRICE']['VALUE'];
        $newData['PROP_PERFORMANCE'][] = $element['PROP_PERFORMANCE']['VALUE'];
    }
}

dump($newData);
```

**Результат**:

[image: Результат]

Для проверки значений на уникальность при записи в новый массив используйте функцию [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) или оставьте только уникальные значения после создания массива с помощью функции [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Следует отредактировать ответ и разместить код, а не скриншоты.

Comment: @NowhereMan Поправил. Спасибо за уточнение. Результат работы я думаю нет смысла текстом выводить.